# How to set wild card option in codeigniter like query with associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

As title says i can place `'%'` in a like query of Codeigniter

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'
```

for associative array

```
    $array = array('title' => $match, 'page1' => $match, 'page2' => $match);

    $this->db->like($array);

    // WHERE title LIKE '%match%' AND page1 LIKE '%match%' AND page2 LIKE '%match%'
```

for more clarification my model has function which handles most of select query in i send an array parameter to retrieve results

```
function getTableData($table='', $fields='', $like=array(),$like1=array())
 {

    //Check For like statement
    if(is_array($like) and count($like)>0)      
        $this->db->like($like); 

    if(is_array($like1) and count($like1)>0)

        $this->db->or_like($like1); 

    //Check For Fields   
    if($fields!='')

            $this->db->select($fields);

    else        
        $this->db->select();

    $result = $this->db->get();

//pr($result->result());
    return $result;

 }
```

This is my generic function so while sending as parameter or by modifying function how can i use wild card placing third parameter with default `'both'` working as it is.

with third parameter i control the placing of `%` , But when i use a associative array how can i implement wildcard placing in Codeigniter.
How can i use it in associative array for different column.Is it possible?. I know i can use custom query and currently i m using it. For any help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I looked core DB_active_rec.php file. Please try this one:

```
$this->db->like($array, false, 'before');
```

/system/database/DB_active_rec.php line 571:

```
 /**
 * Like
 *
 * Generates a %LIKE% portion of the query. Separates
 * multiple calls with AND
 *
 * @param   mixed
 * @param   mixed
 * @return  object
 */
public function like($field, $match = '', $side = 'both')
{
    return $this->_like($field, $match, 'AND ', $side);
}
```

Comment: `CI_DB_active_record::like()` just accept 3 arguments. `_like()` method is `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

use as many `like` as you need in your query. E.g:

```
$this->db->like('title', $title, 'after')->like('page1', $page1)->like('page2', $page2, 'after')->get('table');
```

Comment: i know i can use like many times is it possible for assoc array for my generic function

Answer (score 0):

You can use like() several times:

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->like('page1', 'match');
$this->db->like('page2', 'match');
```

or if PHP >5 use chained:

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match')->like('page1', 'match')->like('page2', 'match');
```

if you have an array of values, use foreach():

```
//considering $like = array('field' => 'value', 'field2' => 'value2');
foreach ($like as $field=> $value)
{
    $this->db->like($field, $value);
}
```